# Error with managedObjectContext coredata entity or TopViewController

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I want to create app with TableView that has 2 Tabbaritems (Task, List, Setting(is not important)- as show below in the picture

[image].

and I want to manage core data. I want to store core data to Task and to List. And want to link the core data from the List to the Task but i get error.. Here is my code in the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];

ItemListTableViewController *itemList = (ItemListTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
itemList.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

TaskListTableViewController *taskList = (TaskListTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
taskList.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

return YES;
}
```

Before I make only 1 Tabbar (List), everything works find but I want to put another tabbar (Task) and manageObject as I mentioned above. When I run the app, it work, but when I click on the List tabbar, it error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'List''
```

Thanks for your help..

Comment: `itemList` and `taskList` are the same `topViewController`.

Comment: how to make different topViewController?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in comments, your itemList and taskList both refer to the same view controller.

```
ItemListTableViewController *itemList = (ItemListTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;

TaskListTableViewController *taskList = (TaskListTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
```

The only difference is that in one case you *cast* it as a different class.  In fact you need to access the view controller for the second tab - this can be found in the viewControllers property of the tabbarcontroller.  The first item in this array (index 0) corresponds to the view controller for the first tab, so you correctly have

```
UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
```

In the same way, the view controller for the second tab is at index 1, so you should have

```
UINavigationController *taskNavController = tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
```

and then you can set

```
TaskListTableViewController *taskList = (TaskListTableViewController *)taskNavController.topViewController;
```

(Looking again at your image of the tabbar, I see I’ve got the indices the wrong way round: taskList relates to the first tab, index 0, and itemList is the second tab, index 1.